# Not let Scroll View Appear Larger when made Larger But Instead Make the Overflow Text Appear if you Scroll More, Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code I have so far in XAML

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding EquationString}" />
            <Entry Grid.Row="1" x:Name="entry" Placeholder="Put Answer Here" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" x:Name="btnCheck" Text="Check Answer"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding CheckMessageString}"/>
            <BoxView Grid.Row="4" Color="Black" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="5" BackgroundColor="White">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                                   PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"
                                   BackgroundColor="White"/>
                <Grid.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                                    TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                </Grid.Effects>
            </Grid>
            <BoxView Grid.Row="6" Color="Black" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnClear" Text="Clear"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnAnalyze" Text="Analyze"/>
            </Grid>
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ResultString}"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text= "{Binding WorkString}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
```

Here is what the view originally looks like
[image: Before]

When I press the button Analyze the Text WorkString changes be 4 \n. However I do not want the size of the drawing canvas to change.
[image: After that I do not want to happen]

Instead what I want to happen is that the size of everything stays the same as before I pressed the button except that the overflow text is now scrollable. In which you have to scroll in order to see that text. Can you guys please assist me with how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want fix size on scrollview ,just hard code the last height of RowDefinition, do not use `Auto` .

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>  //this line
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```